# Select Values from one Table and adding it to another table while having Same PK

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables
Table 1 Schema:

```
Table1:: Product_Report Column:: PId, PReportName, PReportSize
```

And Second Table Schema:

```
Table2:: Product Column:: PId, PName, PSize, PCategory
```

In both table `PId` is PrimaryKey. I want to add `PReportCategory` as new column in `Product_Report` (Table1) in that value of `PReportCategory` is selected from `PCategory` of `Product` (Table2)

Something like:

```
 INSERT into Product_Report (PReportCategory) VALUES Select PCategory from Product where (I guess here need help)
```

If I am right to path I am following then I guess in where condition I need help if not then please help me to construct query

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Q: "I want to add `PReportCategory` as new column in `Product_Report`"

```
ALTER TABLE Product_Report
  ADD PReportCategory BIGINT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ref Product.PCategory'
```

(Use an appropriate datataype in place of `BIGINT`, I added that as a placeholder datatype for the column.)

Q: "... value of `PReportCategory` is selected from `PCategory` of `Product`"

```
UPDATE Product_Report t
  JOIN Product s
    ON s.PId = t.PId
   SET t.PReportCategory = s.PCategory
```

This would leave NULL values for `PReportCategory` in rows in `Product_Report` that don't have a matching row found in `Product`.

---

It's not at all clear what problem this is attempting to solve, i.e. why it's necessary to add this column and populate it. But this example of MySQL syntax demonstrates how we would 1) add a column to a table and 2) populate that column from values in rows in another table, matched based on the values of `PId`